# How do I make my covenant work?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I like the idea of the Blue Sentinels.  I absolutely hate the invasion system of the Soul's serious, but I love the multiplayer co-op aspect of it.  And, in some strange way, I feel that I should punish those that think they can get away from trouncing people for the laughs.  So, I joined the convenant and hoped to start dispensing justice.

Only...wait one moment.  Justice can't be dispensed.  Not only do I need a cracked blue eye orb AND hope to be in a server and location that there's a sinner...but I have to be human to do it?  That just seems all kinds of wrong.  And with PvP focused characters setting out to just destroy other people in game, how am I supposed to make this viable and get up to the 100 or so kills that they're expecting of me?  Is this even viable at this point, or is the Blue Sentinels a waste of my time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not necessarily need a Cracked Blue Eye Orb to advance in the covenant. By wearing the Guardian's Seal, a ring that you get upon joining the covenant, you can be summoned by members of the Way of the Blue, a different covenant, when they are invaded. Of course, you still need to be human to be summoned.

As for dispensing justice... yeah, you're kinda out of luck there. Games in the Soul series are rather more catering to offensive PvP than defensive PvP or "white knighting". However, there are typically hotzones for PvP in each Souls game. As *Dark Souls 2* has only been recently released, the hotzones probably aren't determined yet. Once more people play and get used to the game, these zones will be recognized and you'll have a better time of finding an appropriate area to "deal justice".

Comment: So, drop Blue Sentinels and become a Sunbro?  Got it.  ;3